# Is the following true $\frac{\int_0^{4\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx}{\int_0^{\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx}=\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}-1}$?

Tags: definite-integrals

If $f(x)=e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)$ where $a\in\mathbb Z$.
Let $S_1$ be the area of the region
bounded by $y = f (x)$, with x-axis and between the ordinates $x=0$, $x=4\pi$ , let $S_2$ be the area of the region bounded by $y =f(x)$, with x-axis and between the
ordinates $x=0$ and $x=\pi$. Further let $S_1/S_2=A$

Now one possible conclusion has been provided to me as
$A=(e^{4\pi}-1)/(e^{\pi}-1)$

Please provide me with suitable steps to arrive at this conclusion.

Comment: Could you please try to chose a more expressive title.

Comment: I am sorry. This is my first time at stack exchange and also English is not my native language.

Comment: I edited it a bit; could you check that the proposed answer is as intended. There where mismatched parenthesis thus it is not exactly clear.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am quite unfamiliar with this website, you see.

Comment: For typesetting you can see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference For the title issue just try to say something a bit more detailed. Already saying it is about integrals of trigonometric functions would be better. Following those might avoid some pitfalls.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but could you please help me with this question. It is quite urgent, you see.

Comment: Personally I don't like integrals. I hope somebody else will help you.

Comment: All right, thanks for sparing me your time and helping me improve.

Comment: Since Sameer Baheti's answer shows this is true for integer $a$, you might try a small fraction for $a$ and see what happens.

Comment: @Sameer titles that are only a formula are not ideal because it is difficult to "right click"  them to open in new tab.

Comment: @quid Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4):

> Prove that $$\frac{\int_0^{4\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx}{\int_0^{\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx}=\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}-1}$$, where $a\in \mathbb Z$.

\begin{align*}
&\Rightarrow\int_0^{4\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx+\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx+\int_{3\pi}^{4\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x+\pi}(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x+2\pi}(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x+3\pi}(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}(e^x+e^{x+\pi}+e^{x+2\pi}+e^{x+3\pi})(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx\\
&=(1+e^{\pi}+e^{2\pi}+e^{3\pi})\int_0^{\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx\\
&=\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}-1}\int_0^{\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Yep, thank you a lot

Comment: @YejatKrishna Check this [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex%28%5Csin%5E6%28x%2F2%29%2B%5Ccos%5E4%28x%2F2%29%29+from+0+to+%5Cpi) as per Marty cohen's answer. Your question is limited to integer $a$.

Answer (score 2):

As @Integrand answered, using the power reduction formulae and integration by parts, we have
$$\int e^x(\sin^6 (ax) + \cos^4 (ax))\,dx=$$ $$\frac{e^x }{32} \left(\frac{2 a \sin (2 a x)}{4 a^2+1}+\frac{40 a \sin (4 a x)}{16
   a^2+1}-\frac{6 a \sin (6 a x)}{36 a^2+1}+\frac{\cos (2 a x)}{4 a^2+1}+\frac{10
   \cos (4 a x)}{16 a^2+1}-\frac{\cos (6 a x)}{36 a^2+1}+22\right)$$

If $a$ is an integer, then
$$I_n=\frac{\int_0^{n\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx}{\int_0^{\pi}e^x(\sin^6 ax + \cos^4 ax)\,dx}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{k \pi}=\frac{e^{n\pi  }-1}{e^{\pi }-1}$$ as @Sameer Baheti already answered.

In any other case, this does not hold, as @marty cohen showed.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Use the [Chebyshev formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae), also known as the power-reduction formulas, to turn powers into sums. For instance,
  $$
  \cos^6(\theta)=\frac{1}{32} \left (-15 \cos(2 \theta) + 6 \cos(4 \theta) - \cos(6 \theta) + 10\right)
  $$
- Use integration by parts twice on integrals of the form $\int e^x \cos(m x)\,dx$ with $u=e^x$. You'll get a self-similar integral, which you can then isolate.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

For $a=\frac12$, Wolfy says
$\int_0^{4 π} e^x (sin^6(ax) + cos^4(ax)) dx 
= (e^{4 π} - 1)(61/80)
$
and
$\int_0^{ π} e^x (sin^6(ax) + cos^4(ax)) dx 
= (59e^{ π} - 61)/80
$,
so it is not true for this.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I don't use WA. I cross-checked your claim, and I guess I will use WA from now on instead of trying hard to prove something possibly incorrect. +1 btw.